# Adding attributes to collection requests in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I hope someone can help me puzzle this one out. I'm trying to load some data out of a Magento catalog model using a collection. The code looks like this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('SKU',array('like' => array('%EBOOK%')));
$collection->load();
var_dump($collection->getData());
```

This produces a dump of objects with all the fields in the flat catalog product table, but not the field that I have requested with the `$collection->addAttributeToSelect()` method. No matter what field I specify with this method (even '*'), I cannot get the collection to return anything other than its standard set of fields. I also can't unset any fields using `$collection->removeFieldFromSelect(NULL)` which is supposed to work.

Am I doing something stupid/wrong/both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `echo get_class($collection);`?

Comment: Hi Benmarks. The output is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection`

Comment: This guy ([link]http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/48044/) appears to have had exactly the same problem at some point as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you call `getData()` on the collection, but not on a product of this collection.

I never really analyzed why this happens, but if you use

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

instead of

```
$collection->load();
var_dump($collection->getData());
```

you'll get the data you're expecting.

Comment: Jürgen, you are a genius, thank you! I can't understand why the attributes aren't made available in the straight collection object, but it doesn't really matter - I just checked my SQL logs to see if your method entailed more queries, and in fact it actually seems to produce a more efficient query (at least in terms of less SQL code).

Comment: Collections in Magento model the aggregation, sorting, and filtering of entity data. Think of the collection object as a meta object for accessing results iteratively. See `Mage_Core_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`, `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` and `Varien_Data_Collection`