# Magento Sort Products on Homepage by Price

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using the modern template, with a new.phtml for the homepage. This gives me all of my products on the homepage. I am having an issue with my products being sorted by price. I have changed all of the points that could sort any kind of product to sort by price. But this doesnt seem to work.

I have also found on another page [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304031/adding-attributes-to-collection-requests-in-magento):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('title');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC');
$collection->load();
```

And added it to the top, then changed the if statement from:

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if (($_products = $collection) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
```

I haven't quite gotten how this works. All I get is the short description, and the price. All of the other attributes don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the code.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC');
$collection->load();
```

I found farther down in the code where it was calling the small image, not the base image.

I also found that If you call the attributes the right name then it kinda helps. changed title to name.